# Swift 3: Dict from only one object in struct in array

Tags: swift, nsmutablearray

I have a `struct` that looks like:

```
struct nameStruct {
    let name: String
    let index: Int
}
```

I have an `NSMutableArray` that contains about 50 objects of this `struct`

Right now, I fill the contents of my `namesDict` with

```
let namesDict:[String: Any] = ["names" : namesArray]
```

However, because I only need the `index` object for sorting, I'd like to only add the `name` attribute to the dictionary, something like this:

```
let namesDict:[String: Any] = ["names" : namesArray.name]
```

or, because of swift's nature:

```
let namesDict:[String: Any] = ["names" : (namesArray as! [nameStruct]).name]
```

(focus on the .name part which obviously doesn't work in Swift)

Right now, my best guess would be to create a new array in a loop, only adding the `name` of the contents of my `namesArray` - but if there was a way to do this in one line without another array "in between", this would be really nice.

Comment: Where's this alleged `NSMutableArray`? BTW - do not use `NSMutableArray` in Swift.

Comment: It is Swift convention to name your structures starting with an uppercase letter

Comment: The array is available throughout the whole class, declared right at the top. Why shouldn't I use NSMutableArray? I've read something along the lines a couple of days ago but kinda ignored it, I'd love to know so if you got an article on that, please share

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks for the advice, mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map`.

```
let namesDict: [String: Any] = ["names": namesArray.map({ ($0 as! nameStruct).name })]
```

Comment: Wonderful, just what I needed, thanks a lot, will tick in 2 minutes, remind me if I forget haha

Comment: @LeoDabus If the array is known ahead of time to always contain `nameStruct`s then force-casting is perfectly fine, and if the array contains something else that's a programmer error (and therefore blowing up is appropriate). That said, if it's acceptable for the array to contain something else, then `flatMap` plus conditional casting is a good idea.

Comment: @KevinBallard "flatMap plus conditional casting is a good idea." Not necessarily, that makes the failures silent, which might be preferable in some situations. But in some situations, it might be worse than crashing.